# Use DecimalFormat with StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder, decimalformat

What is the most efficient way to use an instance of *DecimalFormat* together with a *StringBuilder*? When numbers are appended to a string in a loop, for example. There is `format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos)`, but that uses a *StringBuffer* and not a *StringBuilder*, so it is not compatible, and there is also `formatToCharacterIterator(Object obj)` but that both must create an object for the iterator and does not work with primitive types, so it also requires additional potential boxing.

It seems to me calling `format(long number)` to produce a string and append it to the *StringBuilder* is the easiest option, but having to create a string just to append it seems to be kinda defeating the purpose of the *StringBuilder*. Is there really no other option?

**Edit:** I have decided to do some measurements to see the performance difference between these options. Based on the [OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/text/DecimalFormat.java) implementation, it seems all methods eventually get routed to either `format(long, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)` or `format(double, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)` (with the exception of large *BigInteger* and *BigDecimal*), so it would seem when appending just numbers, this way will always be faster with *StringBuffer*.

And indeed, directly using *StringBuffer* is about 20 % faster on my machine than via *StringBuilder* and intermediate string. However, the opposite is true when no number formatting is done and only strings are appended – then *StringBuffer* is 20 % slower. But considering formatting a number is about 5 times slower than simply appending a string, *StringBuilder* seems to be only ever more efficient when there are significantly more appends than formats.

Comment: *"defeating the purpose of the StringBuilder"* --- Not at all. The main purpose of `StringBuilder` is to build a string, **one piece at a time**. The result of `DecimalFormat.format()` is just one such piece. Sure it would be better to bypass the intermediate string, but that in no way defeats the purpose of `StringBuilder`, i.e. concatenating *many* pieces.

Comment: @Andreas Hence "kinda". I agree the main purpose is concatenating many pieces and preventing duplicating the whole string, but many small string instances could also make an impact. However, taking a look at OpenJDK, it seems `format(long number)` is creating a *StringBuffer* under the hood, so that leaves me wondering whether I shouldn't change everything to it, since it is eventually created anyway.

Comment: Since they never bothered, in all their performance tuning of the system, to add overloads using `StringBuilder`, it appears that the performance overhead of the `synchronized` methods of `StringBuffer` is nothing compared to what `DecimalFormat.format()` is otherwise doing. So the question for you is whether using a new `StringBuffer` every time you call `format()` is better or worse than using `StringBuffer` for all the other *pieces* being added to it. You could profile the code, but I'd bet it makes very little difference, given everything else going on. You're micro-optimizing. Stop.

Comment: There will be no way around actually profiling this. Get JMH, read a quick tutorial about it and then measure your code with it. Takes maybe 15 minutes and then you have your results. Everything else is just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can ascertain that the additional String and StringBuffer creation is an actual real-world bottleneck in your application, I suspect you are worrying unnecessarily. It's true that if we could re-invent the history of the JDK, these calls probably would have been defined as taking Appendable. But the authors may well have considered adding a corresponding method when StringBuilder and Appendable were added in Java 5 and decided it was not worth it.

Remember that in modern JVMs, the creation and disposal of temporary objects doesn't have the performance overhead that it once used to. In addition, various flavours of NumberFormat-- including DecimalFormat-- actually provide an internal 'fast path' (see the fastFormat() method) that avoids the StringBuffer creation you mention (though not the temporary String creation). The JVM also generally optimises for uncontended synchronisation as you will have here.

If a profile genuinely shows that DecimalFormat.foramt() is a bottleneck to your application, then there is a chance you may need to consider implementing a specific method to include the optimisations you require. But I suspect you'll find that it's not actually an issue.